# How to store pandas dataframe information in a csv file

Tags: python, scrape

I am new to scraping and python. I am trying to scrape multiple tables from this URL: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Game_of_Thrones_episodes. I did the scraping and now I am trying to save the dataframe to a csv file. I tried but it just stores the the first table from the page.

code:

```
from pandas.io.html import read_html
page = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Game_of_Thrones_episodes'

wikitables = read_html(page, index_col=0, attrs={"class":"wikitable plainrowheaders wikiepisodetable"})

print ("Extracted {num} wikitables".format(num=len(wikitables)))



for line in range(7):
  df= pd.DataFrame(wikitables[line].head())
  df.to_csv('file1.csv')
```

Comment: `I tries but failed`, what's the error?

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: `read_html` should give you list with `dataframes` - so you don't have to convert it to `dataframe` but write it directly - ie. `wikitables[0].to_csv('file0.csv')`, `wikitables[1].to_csv('file1.csv')`

Comment: Sorry. I will keep that it mind  for the future

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reshape the list of dataframes into a single dataframe and then you need to export it to csv file.

```
wikitable = wikitables[0]

for i in range(1,len(wikitables)):
  wikitable = wikitable.append(wikitables[i],sort=True)

wikitable.to_csv('wikitable.csv')
```

Comment: Please accept the answer if it helped. It helps the community at large in recognizing the correct answer. You can do that by clicking the tick mark next the answer.Cheers.

Comment: Done. Sorry for the bad internet connection.

Comment: Can you please upvote my question? I am banned from asking question. I improved my qustion format and corrected spelling

Answer (score 0):

You forgot

```
import pandas as pd
```

but you don't need it because `read_html` gives list of dataframes and you don't have to convert it o dataframes. You can write it directly.

```
from pandas.io.html import read_html

url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Game_of_Thrones_episodes'

wikitables = read_html(url, index_col=0, attrs={"class":"wikitable plainrowheaders wikiepisodetable"})

print("Extracted {num} wikitables".format(num=len(wikitables)))

for i, dataframe in enumerate(wikitables):
    dataframe.to_csv('file{}.csv'.format(i))
```